# Wordpress set featured image javascript

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm uploading an image to my server by URL. The URL is sent by Ajax Call, PHP handles the upload and send back the image ID to ajax call. After that I need to set the image as featured image but I can't get it working.

I've already confirmed that data sent back to ajax call is the correct image ID, but when using the following code, nothing happens:

```
wp.media.featuredImage.set( data ); //data is the ID of the image sent by PHP
```

I guess I'm missing something but can't figure out what.

Comment: check this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41300/128983)

Comment: @Sohrab thanks for your comment. I want to make it with javascript using wp.media API. My PHP code already uploads the file and "attach" it to post, but I want to set it as featured image with javascript/jquery.

Comment: It seems like an unnecessary extra step to do this with jQuery.  You should just use ```set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachment_id );```  at the end of the script you use to upload the media in the first place.

Comment: The point here is make this while creating a new post. If I don't use jquery it will not set the image and respective preview. Already tested it and it doesnt set the image since it's a new post. If I'm making this to a published post, it will update it without issues. Can't make it work with new post.

Comment: Are you using the wp_insert_post method on your backend to create a post?  This method returns a Post ID, so you can simply add the new image to that post very easily.  Right now you are returning an attachment ID, and you can't attach an image to an image.  Can you provide your backend code so we can see what you are doing?  I am not able to see what you are doing to create a post.

Comment: Sorry. The post is created in real time. It's used jQuery with ajax call to get external information. Only using PHP to necessary operations (get categories, upload image and attach it to post - this doesn't make it as featured image). This is basically an automation method. Since the image is uploaded and attached to post, I only need to click the "featured image" box and select it, but I would like to create a 100% automation.